# sed Extract unique characters within each line

Tags: regex, awk, sed, replace, sh

I want to get unique chars within each line using regular expressions in a Shell Script (`sh`).
In other words, I want to remove any further occurrence of a char within each line.

I'm trying to answer this question:
"*What characters do appears in each line?*"

For example, I'm trying to do something like this:

```sh
echo '1.Hi
2.This is
3.a huge file
4.with repeated chars
5.per
6.line' | sed 's/MYSTERIOUS_REGEX/MYSTERIOUS_REPLACE/g'
```

And the expected output is:

```
1.Hi
2.This 
3.a hugefil
4.with repadcs
5.per
6.line
```

This is the explanation:

- Line 1: **there isn't any repeated chars**
- Line 2: '`i`', '`s`' **repeated**
- Line 3: ' ', '`e`' **repeated**
- Line 4: '`e`', '`a`', '`t`', '`e`', '`d`', ' ', '`c`', '`h`', '`a`', '`r`' **repeated**
- Line 5: **there isn't any repeated chars**
- Line 6: **there isn't any repeated chars**

**OBS**:

- If you achieve this using `sh` and `sed` you obtain 5⭐s
- If you achieve this using  other tools (`bash`, `awk` etc), you obtain 3⭐s

---

̶D̶i̶s̶t̶r̶a̶c̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶ **HINT**:

The following regex matches lines which don't have repeated chars: **`^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!.*\1))*$`**

```sh
echo "bleh" | grep -P '^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!.*\1))*$'
```

> ble

```sh
echo "fooo" | grep -P '^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!.*\1))*$'
```

> (empty)

---

---

Comment: What are the start we can obtain?

Comment: Also, output of line 4 should be `4.with repadcs` (or at least that's what my solution shows).

Comment: `([A-Za-z])(?=.*\1)` matches  characters that appear more than once. Can sed be used to extract those characters from the string, leaving the unique characters, equivalent of the following in Ruby: `s = "littlier"; s.chars - s.scan(/([A-Za-z])(?=.*\1)/).flatten #=> ["e", "r"]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-sed` solution:

```sh
sed -E ':a;s/((.).*)\2/\1/;ta' file

1.Hi
2.This
3.a hugefil
4.with repadcs
5.per
6.line
```

Alternative `awk` non-regex solution (should work in any awk version):

```sh
awk '{
   delete seen
   for (i=1; i<=length(); ++i) {
      ch = substr($0,i,1)
      if (!seen[ch]++) printf "%s", ch
   }
   print ""
}' file

1.Hi
2.This
3.a hugefil
4.with repadcs
5.per
6.line
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed -E ':a;s/((.).*)\2/\1/;ta' file` the `g` flag is unnecessary since the `.*` is greedy and therefore works backwards through the line.

Comment: Thanks @potong yes that’s a fair point that g is not needed

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FS="" '
{
  delete seen
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(!seen[$i]++){
      val=(i>1?val:"") $i
    }
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v FS="" '              ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as NULL here.
{
  delete seen               ##Deleting seen array here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){       ##Traversing through all field of current line here.
    if(!seen[$i]++){        ##checking condition if current field value is NOT present in seen.
      val=(i>1?val:"")$i ##Then add its value in val variable and keep concatenating these kind of values, if they pass above condition.
    }
  }
  print val                 ##Printing val here.
}
'  Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```